# What's the simplest way to compute the average distance to the center of points in the n-ball?

Tags: calculus

Define the standard $n$-ball as usual:

$$B_n(R) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|_2\leq R\}$$

How to compute the mean distance to the center of $B_r(R)$?

Specifically I am looking for simple, intuitive ways to approach this problem.

---

What I tried (not very simple nor very intuitive...)

Divide the $n$-ball into all the *(n-1)*-spheres inside it (i.e. $S^{n-1}(r) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|_2=r\}$ for $0\leq r \leq R$) and denote its sufrace area by $S_{n-1}(r)$

Then one computes

$$\frac{\int_0^R r S_{n-1}(r)dr}{V_n(R)}$$

where $V_n(R)$ is the volume of the $n$-ball.

Simplifying the above expression and using the formulas for the surface area and volume of an $n$-sphere

$$S_{n}(r) = \frac{2\pi^{\frac{n + 1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}r^n$$

$$V_n(r)=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}r^n$$

One arrives at

$$\frac{\int_0^R r \frac{2\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}r^{n-1}dr}{\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}R^n}=\frac{2\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}{R^n\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\int_0^R  r^ndr=\frac{2\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\frac{R}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}R$$

---

Is there a simpler approach?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ represents the distance to the origin then
$$\mathbb{P}(X\le r)=\cases{0& if $r<0$\cr r^n/R^n& if $0\le r\le R$\cr
1& if $r\ge R$}$$
So, the density function of $X$ is
$$f_X(r)=n\frac {r^{n-1}}{R^n}\mathbb{I}_{[0,R]}(r)$$
Hence
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{n}{R^n}\int_0^R r^ndr=\frac{n}{n+1}R$$
Which is the expected distance to the origine.

Comment: That's simpler than my method! +1. I wonder if the two solutions are the same? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @NunoCalaim the same answer, you just simplify $\Gamma(1+n/2)=(n/2)\Gamma(n/2)$.